# Duplicated Values in Array

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function outside of main that scans over duplicated values in a string array without using any c++ library functions and duplicated values to an empty string ""

An array I'm using to test is

```
string duplicates[7] = { "apple", "bear", "apple", "daddy", "bear", "daddy", "sunny" };
```

However it is not working as it is not fully removing all the duplicated values.

```
int Duplicaters(string arr[], int a)
{
int a = updatenewsize;
string str;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    str = arr[i];

    for(int j = i + 1; j <= updatenewsize; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] == str) 
        {
            for(int k = j; k <= size - 1; k++) ///< size - 1 for "removal"
            {
                arr[k] = arr[k + 1]; 
            }
            updatenewsize--;  ///< update the size after we "removed"
        }
    }
}
return updatenewsize;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that this specific array will trigger the logical bug in the shown code. Try a simple three element array, with all three strings being the same. You indicated you already know how to use a debugger. Great. Use your debugger to step through your algorithm, using an array containing just three identical strings, and the logical bug should be very obvious.

Comment: @JModi except that this is C++ so it's not a duplicate of a Java question.

Comment: @JModi Most the answers to the "duplicate" use Java library functions that C++ mostly doesn't have. The accepted answer to that question will require some amount of effort to translate to C++.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see it was c++.

Comment: @user4581301 I believe that my program is incrementing even if it is the same value, instead of incrementing it only once . I'm still trying to find a solution to that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm mostly tripping up on the increment counter, which I have checked in the debugger to be incrementing even if it is the same value.

Comment: @alfred my first comment was essentially useless after I read your question better. I've deleted it.

Comment: _"I have not been able"_ _"it seems that my program trips up"_ These are not valid problem statements.

Comment: What you want in your question is the code (preferably in [mcve] form), a "This is the output I expect" block, a "This is the output I got" block, and any useful information you gleaned from running your program through a debugger. If you have't stepped through the program with a debugger, do that now. Saves a lot of time.

Comment: @user4581301 Okay, I will check it out. Thank you.

Comment: If STL is allowed, push them to a vector , and use erase-remove to remove the duplicates , then copy back to the array

Comment: Roughly put you want to 1. Replace duplicate strings in the array with `''` and 2. Count the total number of duplicates in the entire array. Can you use `vector` or `sort`?

Comment: @seccpur that's the real world solution, but the first sentence says no C++ library functions.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla  Yeah but I 'm  supposed  to do this without vector  or sort.

Comment: once you code finds a duplicate and changes it to empty string it count it again as duplicate of an empty string :), and again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. You cannot "remove" values from an array. Arrays by definition are fixed size. What you *can* do is overwrite duplicate values and shift the unique ones to the left. You do this while keeping track of what the new size of the array should be (in memory it's still the same size, but for practical purposes we don't care about the stuff at the end any more).  I hope you don't mind some clean up with variable names. I did this to make the intent clear. The function will return the size of the "new" array with unique values.

```
int removeDuplicatedValues(string array[], int size)
{
    int newsize = size;
    string str;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        str = array[i];
        // note that we increment until j < newsize here because
        // we are "shrinking" the array on every match!
        for(int j = i + 1; j < newsize; j++)
        {
            if(array[j] == str) ///< we found a match
            {
                for(int k = j; k < size - 1; k++) ///< size - 1 for "removal"
                {
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];  ///< shift everybody else down
                }
                newsize--;  ///< update the size after we "removed"
            }
        }
    }
    return newsize;
}
```

You would use it like this. The array should now only print out the unique strings and we've virtually shrunk the size of the array to be just the elements we care about.

```
int main()
{
    string duplicates[7] = { "apple", "bear", "apple", "daddy", "bear", "daddy", "sunny" };
    int length = removeDuplicatedValues(duplicates, 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << duplicates[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this quick test looks like

```
apple bear daddy sunny
```

If you want to know how many duplicates you "removed" from the array at this point, you can do it with simple math. Since you know the fixed size (in this case `7`) and the `length` variable returned from our function has the number of unique elements.

```
int duplicates = 7 - length; ///< how many duplicates did we have?
```

Comment: Maybe I am putting it wrong, but when I put this code into the compiler, it returned apple bear bear bear .

Comment: @alfred Hmm what compiler are you using?  I've confirmed it's working on multiple versions of g++ and clang.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studios. It seems that my complier was initially glitching so I had to restart the compiler and do it again, and this time it turned out right. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: However, when I did make the array print out all 7 elements , it had sunny sunny sunny sunny at the end, is there a way to replace all the duplicated values with empty strings ("") while shifting the unique values to the left?

Comment: That data is useless to you after you remove all the duplicates, so I'm not sure why you would want to set it to empty strings. The way the algorithm works is that the last element in the array will be repeated because it was copied to the element left of it once for each duplicate found.  Anyway, if you really want to clear out these strings. Just do `for(int i = length; i < 7; i++) { array[i] = "" };`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @alfred Glad to help. Please accept my answer if it got things working for you.

Comment: sorry, I'm new at this, How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

After duplicates are replaced with the empty string, you are counting `"" == ""` duplicates on further `i`. You should see it in cout.

Instead of assigning the empty string I would swap `array[j]`and `array[n - 1]` and decrement `n`.

Answer (score 0):

you can using this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
string* arrayNew;
int arrayNewSize=0;
string *removeDuplicatedValues(string *array, int arraySize)
{
    int duplicatecounter = 0;
    string empty = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            string s = array[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arraySize; j++){
                if (array[j] == s)
                {
                    array[j] = empty;
                }
            }
            if(array[i]!=empty){
                arrayNewSize++;
            }
        }
        arrayNew = new string[arrayNewSize];
        int k=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++){
            if(array[j]!=empty){
                arrayNew[k++]=array[j];
            }  
        }
        return arrayNew;

} 
int main () {
    string duplicates[] = {"apple","bear","apple","daddy","bear","daddy","sunny"};
    int arraySize = (sizeof(duplicates) / sizeof(string));
    string* finalArrayP;
    finalArrayP=removeDuplicatedValues(duplicates,arraySize);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayNewSize; i++){
        cout << "newarray[i] is  " << finalArrayP[i] << endl;
    }
    delete [] arrayNew;
    return 0;
}
```